# Need to Programmatically Recompile all Script Tasks in DTSX Packages after Mass Find-And-Replace

Tags: build, ssis, compilation, dts

An upcoming move of our Data Warehouse has us needing to change many Connection Strings and UNC File Paths located in VBA Script Tasks within DTSX Packages.

We've performed a mass find-and-replace but when changing Script Tasks using this method, the binaries run during DTSX Package execution don't get recompiled at run time, resulting in the find-and-replaced changes not being reflected in the Script Task's execution.

I've found some articles on how to do it in SQL Server 2008 and 2012, but we're using SQL Server 2014 and the code examples here aren't working for me:(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jason_howell/2013/03/05/script-component-recompile-in-sql-server-2012-integration-services-ssis-to-refresh-metadata/).

Some of the questions in the comments speak to my problem but none of the "I fixed this this way [navigate to path and include references]" are working for me -- I don't see these assemblies, and with the changes between 2008 to 2012, and now us on 2014, I'm uncertain whether these libraries are even included in my distribution...

So, I have a whole bunch of DTSX files in various sub directories that require their script tasks be recompiled in order for us to go live with these changes. 
I'm hoping to not-have to open every script task in every package manually to force the build of each task.

Thanks in advance for any potential solutions!

Comment: I'm looking for something similar....if I have any updates, I'll let you know

Comment: I was able to accomplish that(yeah, I am feeling like a genius)....I build a Windows Form app with Visual Basic on VisualStudio 2013 that loads an ssis package and recompiles every script task.... I am going to post an answer when I get home :)

Comment: @Hackerman looking forward to your solution.  We're also stuck with this requirement.

Comment: ...check my answer...and, add me on linkedin(in my profile) for further instructions-queries :)

Comment: Did my answer helps you?

Answer (score 6):

I create a `Console` application with the code necesary to recompile every `ScriptTask` inside a `dtsx` package, using `Visual Studio 2013` and `C#` up to `two` levels. Path for every assembly that needs to be referenced are included as comments in the code. `pkgLocation` is the path to the package(in the ends I build a `Windows Form` app, but this is the base and working code:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Design;
  using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
  using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
  using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline;
  using Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting;
  using Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.VSTA;
  using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask;
  using System.IO;

  //Libraries
  //C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Design\v4.0_12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Design.dll
  //C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll
  //C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll
  //C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.VSTA\v4.0_12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.VSTA.dll
  //C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll
  //C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost\v4.0_12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SQLServer.PipelineHost.dll
  //C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask\v4.0_12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll
  //C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.TxScript\v4.0_12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.TxScript.dll
  //C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAScriptingLib\v4.0_12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAScriptingLib.dll

  namespace recompApp
  {
      class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              string pkgLocation;
              Package pkg;
              Application app; 

              //This is the folder where the test package lives!!
              pkgLocation =
                @"C:\TestPackage.dtsx";
              app = new Application();
              pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
              //It's Alive!!!!!!!
              try
              {

                  Executables pExecs = pkg.Executables;

                  foreach (Executable pExec in pExecs)
                  {
                      switch (pExec.GetType().Name)
                      {
                          case "TaskHost":{
                              TaskHost taskHost = (TaskHost)pExec;
                              Console.WriteLine("Executable name = " + taskHost.Name); 
                              //Script Task Outside of a Sequence
                              if (taskHost.InnerObject.ToString().Equals("Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask"))
                              {
                                  ScriptTask task = (ScriptTask)taskHost.InnerObject;
                                  //Load the script project, build and save
                                  task.ScriptingEngine.LoadProjectFromStorage();
                                  task.ScriptingEngine.VstaHelper.Build("");
                                  task.ScriptingEngine.SaveProjectToStorage();
                                  //Cleanup
                                  task.ScriptingEngine.DisposeVstaHelper();
                              }                            
                              break;
                          }
                          case "Sequence":{
                              Executables seqExecs = ((Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Sequence)(pExec)).Executables;
                              foreach(Executable seqExec in seqExecs){
                                  switch (seqExec.GetType().Name)
                                  {
                                      case "TaskHost":
                                          {
                                              TaskHost taskHost = (TaskHost)seqExec;        
                                              //Script Task inside a Sequence Container
                                              if (taskHost.InnerObject.ToString().Equals("Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask"))
                                              {
                                                  Console.WriteLine("Executable name = " + taskHost.Name);
                                                  ScriptTask task = (ScriptTask)taskHost.InnerObject;
                                                  //Load the script project, build and save
                                                  task.ScriptingEngine.LoadProjectFromStorage();
                                                  task.ScriptingEngine.VstaHelper.Build("");
                                                  task.ScriptingEngine.SaveProjectToStorage();
                                                  //Cleanup
                                                  task.ScriptingEngine.DisposeVstaHelper();
                                              }
                                              break;
                                          }
                                  }
                              }
                              break;
                          }                        
                      }                    
                  }
                  //Save the updated xml in the package 
                  string xml;
                  pkg.SaveToXML(out xml, null);
                  File.WriteAllText(pkgLocation, xml);
              }
              catch (Exception e)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
              }

              Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
              Console.ReadKey();
          }

      }
  }
```

> I hope this helps a lots of people outside. I also have the `Visual Basic` version if you need it.

Comment: I've run a variation of your script (to also capture and recompile Script Tasks inside a dataflow) and the script ran, and changed the file, but now I can't open the Package in VS. Digging into the changes applied, it appears to be caused by changing the "Version" attribute of the Script Component to "10", and/or setting <HostIdentifier>SSIS_SC130</HostIdentifier>  (Was SC120)

Comment: I suspect this is ultimately an issue of getting the right versions of various dlls? Did you come across similar issues at any point, and do you have any advice?

Comment: In the comments section are all the DLL files that you need to reference in order to get the project work...also I use Visual Studio 2013...

Comment: Can you post the VB version? Thanks

Comment: I only tested a snipped of the rebuild code. For SQL Server 2016 and VS 2019 the dlls are located in  C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.NAME_OF_THE_LIBRARY\v4.0_13.0.0.0_SOME_NUMBERS\LibraryName it works.