# task.ScriptingEngine.SaveProjectToStorage() returns false

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ssis, compilation, script-task

I am trying to dynamically compile my Script Tasks as per the script here:
[Need to Programmatically Recompile all Script Tasks in DTSX Packages after Mass Find-And-Replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160729/need-to-programmatically-recompile-all-script-tasks-in-dtsx-packages-after-mass?answertab=active#tab-top)

But the following code has been returning false:

```
task.ScriptingEngine.SaveProjectToStorage()
```

I wonder why this happening. Permission issues perhaps? I am at my wits end.
When I run the entire script in a standalone console app it works. But every time I attempt to integrate it to my existing application, I run into issues.